# Can I use Unix socket for local communication between two iOS applications

Tags: ios, sockets, ipc, tcpsocket

Background: I have two iOS applications that need to exchange data **locally** with each other. The ideal scenario is that app A calls app B into foreground using URL scheme, with app A in the background, the two apps could exchange data with each other multiple rounds. I can declare app A the ability to run in background(I have valid reason to do so) so background execution for A is not a problem. I don't want to continue using URL scheme for the data exchange part between two apps because using URL scheme will open the other app and that means these two apps will be opened multiple times if there is multiple rounds of data exchange.

Also please note that these two iOS applications do not belong to the same developer so anything that relies on app group to share data will not work in this case...

Currently I have found a solution using a **Unix Internet Domain Socket** that binds onto the local loopback interface. It is technically working but I don't know if Apple permits this or not? Is there any better way to do this?

**This is the code for the unix socket:**

For the server app(app A):

```
BOOL _listenForConnections = false;
    int listenfd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(8008);
    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    _listenForConnections = true;
    listen(listenfd, 10);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
        NSLog(@"Waiting for connections...");
        while (_listenForConnections)
        {
            __block int connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);
            NSLog(@"Connection accepted");
            char buffer[4096];
            bzero(buffer, 4096);
            NSString *message = @"";
            bool continueReading = true;
            do{
                recv(connfd , buffer , 4096 , 0);
                    continueReading = false;
                NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Received message from client: %@%s", message, buffer]]);
            }while (continueReading);
            char* answer = "Hello World";
            write(connfd, answer, strlen(answer));
            NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Sent response to client"]);
        }
        NSLog(@"Now stop listening for connections");
        close(listenfd);
});
```

Comment: How is that supposed to work? One app is backgrounded, so it has limited execution time. The system will close your socket after a few minutes in the background, wether you have background execution enabled or not. iOS is very restrictive about that (luckily ...), to prevent apps draining battery while not being used actively.
If you want to exchange data or wake up another app, maybe data notifications is what you want.

Comment: Whether this will work, I don't know, never heard anything like it before. I would suspect Apple would not like this. I think the app group thing is the only cross app communication they will allow (guessing). As Martin suggested. It would be worthwhile describing the full use case of what you are trying to do, there might be another solution